# What can be a toy model for $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ in uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology, intuition

What can be a toy model for $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ in uniform topology?

here, uniform topology is the topology induced by the metric $\rho(x, y)=$sup{$\bar{d}(x_i, y_i) ; i \in \mathbb{Z}$}

and $\bar{d}$ is standard bounded metric on $\mathbb R$.

for the same set but in the product topology, I usually think of it as a generalized cartesian coordinates,

I’ve already known that it is useful when dealing with uniform convergence of continuous functions defined on the closed interval of $\mathbb R$.

I think the uniform metric as “the maximal distance” between two continuous functions on the interval.

But still it is hard to visualize.

Could you give me any intuitive “picture” or “toy model” for this topological space?

Comment: Not a toy model, but $\Bbb R^\omega$ in the uniform topology is just a lot of disjoint copies of the linear space $\ell^\infty$, the space of bounded real sequences with the $\sup$-norm. The connected component of the constantly $0$ function is homeomorphic to it, and all other components are too. And there are many components..

Comment: $\rho$ as you define it is not a metric because $\rho(x,y)=\infty$ for some $x,y.$ You can amend this to $\rho(x,y)=\min(1,\sup_i|x_i-y_i|).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thx. But $\bar{d}$ is exactly what you said.

Comment: Sorry. I mis-read it.